# Anyone with Mac Pro, please help for CPU advice

Tags: after-effects, mac, cinema4d

I'm about to buy a Mac Pro, possibly an iMac instead, in a few days for extensive 3D and video work. I was able to try an online CPU stress test which renders complex video frames on the iMac but I need someone that has a Mac Pro. If you could go to the link below and click on the third bottom option "Stress Test," and tell me exactly how many seconds it took to render the first frame. This would be greatly appreciated thank you!

http://silver.urih.com/

Also let me know what your processor is/specs are. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I have mid 2012 Mac Pro with two E5645 Xeon's and result is 01:10

[image: About this Mac]

But I don't think that SilverBench is best benchmark. Guys who use Cinema 4D usually use Cinebench by Maxon. My results in Cinebench:

[image: Cinebench R15 results]